# Phalcon install on cPanel

Tags: cpanel, phalcon

I want to install Phalcon on cPanel. I have cPanel on my dedicated server running CentOS 6.6.

So far I followed the instructions [HERE](https://github.com/thecpaneladmin/EA-PhalconPHP).

```
cd /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/
git clone https://github.com/thecpaneladmin/EA-PhalconPHP.git .
/scripts/easyapache
```

I tried to configure current profile, and when EasyApache starts there is no such module to select like Phalcon.

In instruction there is: From here, select Phalcon from the list of PHP modules. But it is not on the list

I also tried to edit /usr/local/lib/php.ini by adding the line extension=phalcon.so bt it won't work

How to install that module if I can't select it in easy Apache.

Is there another approach to install Phalcon on system with cPanel?

Answer (score 0):

it will not working without adding Phalcon to php.ini
add this extension in php.ini

```
extension=phalcon.so
```

and run simply terminal commands as root:

Go to location

```
cd /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/
```

Copy git file

```
git clone https://github.com/thecpaneladmin/EA-PhalconPHP.git .
```

Run easyapache

```
/scripts/easyapache
```

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon in easyapache 3 is now deprecated.

It is however available in easyapache 4.